# Identify exact XPath for ImportXML in Gsheet

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I want to scrape 52 Week low price (which is 238.00 for today) from [this website](http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/media-entertainment/erosinternationalmedia/EIM) in Google Spreadsheet. I'm using the `=IMPORTXML` function.

To get Xpath, I'm using XPath Helper Chrome extension which gives me the following path:

```
/html/body/center[2]/div/div/div[8]/div[@id='nChrtPrc']/div[@id='content_full']/div[@id='content_bse']/div[@class='PT10 clearfix']/div[@class='FR']/div[@class='PB3 gD_11'][2]/span[@id='b_52low']
```

I tried using

`=IMPORTXML(A1,A2)`

Where, A1 = [URL](http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/media-entertainment/erosinternationalmedia/EIM)
and A2 = `//span[@id='b_52low']`

But not getting the desired result, any help on exact XPath please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xpath worked for me no problem:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/media-entertainment/erosinternationalmedia/EIM","//*[@id='b_52low']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rightly do with quoting:

```
=IMPORTXML("<url>", "//span[@id='b_52low']")
```

Check that you do not misuse `"` (double quotes) twice (for id name and xPath boundaries).

There might be invadlid HTML, and `IMPORTXML` therefore can't read/parse it.